# What to do if you don't want any domain field to be displayed(int status) in DB. Grails

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

class Book {

```
String title
String name
int status
```

}

Comment: "What to do if you don't want any domain field to be displayed(int status) in DB. Grails" - Are you trying to prevent `status` from being displayed, prevent it from being persisted to the database, or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want grails to create the **status** field in the database, you add `static transients = ['status']` to your class.

```
class Book {
   String title
   String name
   int status

   static transients = ['status']
}
```

If you want to save status to the database but do not want the Scaffold to display the status on the screen, you can use `status display: false` in the constaints.

```
class Book {
   String title
   String name
   int status

   static constraints = {
      status display: false
   }
}
```